# Pandas local mins and maxes with dates

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to find the local mins and maxes of data. The data is basically the amount of gallons in a tank each day for about 18 years. I am trying to find the time between each local max to find patterns in when it was filled up.

This is the code for what I have done so far:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates
from matplotlib.dates import date2num
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema

d = pd.read_excel(r'polling_info.xlsx')
print(d)
print("#############")
# print(d.Site_Name.unique()) = ['Thomas Concrete - Lithonia']
# Because there is only one gas-station, we are going to drop the column 'Site_Name'
# We are also going to drop ShipToID, Fuel_Inches, and Tank_Config_Seq_Id
d = d.drop(columns=['Site_Name', 'ShipToID',
                    'Fuel_Inches', 'Tank_Config_Seq_Id'])
print(d)
print("#############")
gallons = d['Gallons'].tolist()
pollDate = d['Poll_Date'].tolist()
date2002 = d['Poll_Date'].head(500).tolist()
gallons2002 = d['Gallons'].head(500).tolist()

dates = matplotlib.dates.date2num(date2002)


n = 5
d['min'] = d.iloc[argrelextrema(d.Gallons.values, np.less_equal, order=n)[
    0]]['Gallons']
d['max'] = d.iloc[argrelextrema(d.Gallons.values, np.greater_equal, order=n)[
    0]]['Gallons']
plt.scatter(d.head(500).index, d['min'].head(500), c='r')
plt.scatter(d.head(500).index, d['max'].head(500), c='g')
plt.plot(d.head(500).index, d.Gallons.head(500))
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Gallons')
plt.show()
print(d.index)
```

This returns the graph

[image: plt of code above]

What I am confused about is the `.index` function. How do I plot this such that the mins and maxes are placed on the corresponding dates of their data points?

I feel like there is a very simple way to do this, but just can't seem to figure it out. If I do dates.index it gives me an attribute error saying there is no attribute 'index'.

How can I iterate over the dates just like .index seems to work to accomplish this?

Or how can I convert from the index to the date of that index?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From my reading of your question, I guess you want to include the date values in the x-axis of your plot. For this, instead of passing index as the first value in your plt.plot() and plt.scatter, you need to provide 'Poll_Date'

```
plt.scatter(d['Poll_Date'].head(500), d['min'].head(500), c='r')
plt.scatter(d['Poll_Date'].head(500), d['max'].head(500), c='g')
plt.plot(d['Poll_Date'].head(500), d.Gallons.head(500))
```

The above code snippet should work if you replace it with the corresponding lines in your code.